# How to write programming code containing the ' character in latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to write programming code in latex using the verbatim environment, but when I write

```
  \begin{verbatim}
     char ch = 'x';
  \end{verbatim}
```

then the ' -characters around x are displayed incorrectly (they look "curly"). How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Load the `upquote` package to fix this issue in verbatim mode.

If you want straight quotes in monospaced text mode (e.g., `\texttt{...}`), or indeed in any other font, then you can use the `\textquotesingle` command defined in the `textcomp` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote,textcomp}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\upquote[1]{\textquotesingle#1\textquotesingle}
\verb|'c'| \texttt{\upquote{h}}
\textsf{\upquote{h}} \upquote{h}
\end{document}
```

This will work well for fonts in any encoding rather than depending on a specific glyph slot (such as `\char13` in the default `OT1` encoding).

Comment: I tried this, but the result of `\begin{verbatim} \textquotesingle \end{verbatim}` is `\textquotesingle` printed out in full.

Comment: "Load the upquote package to fix this issue in verbatim mode."

Comment: This is hands down the best answer here, such a shame it's so far down.

Answer (score 22):

Adding `\usepackage{upquote}` to my preamble was sufficient.

Perhaps older versions of LaTeX or upquote required more work.

Comment: Does this work with the `minted` environment as well?

Comment: @usernumber No idea, sorry. You'll have to test it yourself :)

Comment: THIS! I wish this answer were more upvoted. Worked perfectly for me!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice... I came back here and knew this was the solution because I saw my original upvote from years ago...

Answer (score 7):

I have

[image]

What is wrong?

**New**

If you want to get something like this

[image]

write

```
\makeatletter
\let \@sverbatim \@verbatim
\def \@verbatim {\@sverbatim \verbatimplus}
{\catcode`'=13 \gdef \verbatimplus{\catcode`'=13 \chardef '=13 }} 
\makeatother
```

Comment: The quote is "curly", if I copy a curly quote and paste it into the source code I get a syntax error.

Comment: This only works for the default CMTT font; it won't work if you switch fonts. E.g., with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @Will: It is right. I know. But I wanted to help. And I hope I succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

For displaying source code, you might consider using the `listings` package; it is quite powerful and offers an option to display “straight” quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing curly single right quotes in a verbatim environment, then the single right quote in your typewriter font *is* curly, and that's the correct one to use for what you're doing (which I assume is displaying some C code).

Comment: Well, it is not the correct one to use because if someone copy and paste the code from my pdf-document then he or she will get a syntax error,  because the compiler is expecting the straight single quote...

Comment: I think that uckelman meant that it is a straight single quote, it just looks curly in the font used...  Did you try copying and pasting to see if the character itself was modified?

Comment: Yes, I pasted it into emacs and it does not look as a straight quote.

Comment: Quotes in general are curly, but the quote keys on keyboards (i.e., in ascii) *are* straight. So if you're trying to represent "what to type" then it's wrong to use curly quotes.

Answer (score 1):

\textsf{``} and \textsf{''} come pretty close to straight quotes.   No need for using any special packages.

Comment: Thanks, that’s the only thing that worked in my odd combination of \setmathfont[range… and CMU Serif.

Answer (score -3):

This is what I got from another source, and this works.

Use `` to start the double quotes (this symbol is below ~ symbol on our keyboard)

Use '' to close the double quotes (this symbol is below the " symbol on our keyboard)

So, `` quote double, unquote double''

Same goes for single quotes, `quote single, unquote single'